# RStudio: installing packages

Tags: r, r-package

When I try to install a package in R studio it returns this error:

```
Error in file("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rbslandau/statistics_multi/master/Data/installed_pkgs.txt",  : 
cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rbslandau/statistics_multi/master/Data/installed_pkgs.txt",  :
InternetOpenUrl failed: 'đ´O'
Warning in install.packages :
unable to access index for repository   https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4:
cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/PACKAGES'
```

I have tried all possible solutions from previous questions but it didn't help.

Can somebody please help me with this issue?

Comment: Which package are you installing? Can you post the entire error log.

Comment: pkgs <- readLines(file("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rbslandau/statistics_multi/master/Data/installed_pkgs.txt", "r"))
str(pkgs)
install.packages(pkgs)

Comment: I got the same error for any package that I try to install.

Comment: Are you using a Mac OS by any chance?